# A step in the proof of Gauss's lemma in Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand the proof on Wikipedia of [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28Riemannian_geometry%29#Proof) (which is more or less the same as in do Carno's textbook). I am having a hard time understanding the final step where in the notation of Wikipedia, we want to compute:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\langle v+sw_n ,v+sw_n \rangle.$$
They state that this is equal to $2\langle v,w_n\rangle$ but I don't see why. Shouldn't the answer be $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}s^2||w_n|| = 2s||w_n||$? (note that $\langle v,w_n\rangle = 0$.)

Comment: Haven't looked in detail, but my guess is that this is being evaluated at $s=0.$